# Show/Hide DIV by Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I am trying to show/hide a form inside a div, conditional on multiple checkboxes. If all 3 are checked, the div contents should appear. If one or more are unchecked, the div contents should be hidden.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="style/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            if ($('#checkbox1, #checkbox2, #checkbox3').is(:checked)) {
               $('#purchaseForm').show();
            } else {
               $('#purchaseForm').hide();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="span6">
            I understand that...<br>
            I understand that...<br>
            I understand that...<br><br>

        <div id="purchaseForm">
            [form]
        </div>          
        </div>

        <div class="span6">
            <input name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="" type="checkbox"><br>
            <input name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="" type="checkbox"><br>
            <input name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" value="" type="checkbox"><br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `is(:checked)` is this how your code is? that should be `is(':checked')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function(){
    var checks = $('#checkbox1, #checkbox2, #checkbox3');

    checks.click(function(){
        if (checks.filter(':checked').length == checks.length) {
            $('#purchaseForm').show();
        } else {
            $('#purchaseForm').hide();
        }
    }).triggerHandler('click')


})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6j3Cp/)

Answer (score 1):

You are currently checking to see if any of the checkboxes are checked. Make sure they're all checked.

```
if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#checkbox2').is(':checked') && $('#checkbox3').is(':checked'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the change event of checkboxes **[DEMO Here](http://jsbin.com/etUWoKa/4/edit?js,output)**:

```
$(function(){
var container = $('#container');
var purchaseForm = $('#purchaseForm');
    container.on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
        if(container.find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').length){
        purchaseForm.hide();
        }
        else{
        purchaseForm.show();
        }
    });
    container.find('input[type="checkbox"]:first').change();
});
```

Comment: Updated to use Id for container

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UjeHoYI/1/edit)**

```
$(function(){  
  var $cbx  = $(':checkbox[id^=check]'),
      $form = $('#purchaseForm');  
  $cbx.change(function(){
    $form[$cbx.not(':checked')[0]?'hide':'show']();
  }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Try](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var a = $("#checkbox1");
var b = $("#checkbox2");
var c = $("#checkbox3");
var combined = a.add(b).add(c);
$(combined).click(function() //anyone of combined cliecked event
{
    // if ($('#checkbox1, #checkbox2, #checkbox3').is(':checked'))    this means         one of those is checked
    if ($(a).is(':checked') && $(b).is(':checked') && $(c).is(':checked')) {
        $('#purchaseForm').show();
    } else {
        $('#purchaseForm').hide();
    }
});

});
```